# python web scraping: onclick ajax request returns nothing with status 200

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a table data from a website. The data I want is "hiding" behind an onclick event.

```
<a class="text" onclick="javascript:openPAOnSR_RS('some_sku', 'brandname','divId', 'some_args','OPC Page Details');cmTagAndLink('Open Link','OPC Page Details',null,null,null);">The Click</a>
```

After clicking, there is a post request and some of the details below.

```
Request URL:http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog/tables.do?some_sku=sku&brandKey=brandname&divId=divId
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:23.xxxxxxxxxxx
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

So I wrote the code as below but it did not return anything.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import requests


def get_page_index():
    string_param = {
        'some_sku': 'sku',
        'brandKey': 'brandname',
        'divId': 'divId'
    }

    url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog/tables.do?" + urlencode(string_param)
    try:
        response = requests.post(url=url, data=string_param)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.url, response.content)
            return response.text
        return None
    except RequestException as e:
        print(e)
```

I am getting no output and the status shows 200. How should I get the data "behind" on click event?

Comment: can you Explain when the onclick event occurring? what i comprehend that you request a website and after that you do come click and then a `JS` dialogue box occurs, and behind that `JS` box you data is available ; Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So I have this webpage I am trying to scrape, and there is a onclick link that will initiate a JS dialogue box. I know that I can extract data from the JS box but how do I do the "click" to initiate the JS dialog? The question is I have multiple similar-structured webpage that I am trying to extract info from. I want to write a scraping script that can do the "click" my mouse is doing.

Answer (score 0):

`urllib`  will only respond you with the `html` content, so you can't interfere with the JS stuff on that website, there are modules like `robobrowser` , `scrapy`  but they only click the `html` check boxes or buttons.
so other options with are preferable are.

1) [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) by using a headless browser using `Phantom`.

2) Using [`Scrapy + splash`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

can i ask that after what steps you are doing before clicking the button?
are you clicking on the button after putting some info. or you are just clicking the button as the website appears?